# Vibrational spectrum of a mass disordered chain

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators

Consider a linear spring-mass disordered chain with a large number of masses (say $10^6$ masses). The spring constant $k_i$ of each spring is set to 1. The chain consists of atoms of mass 1 and mass 2 placed randomly such that they have equal concentrations.
The displacements of the particles is given by:

$$ x_{i+1} = (2 - m_i\omega^2)x_i - x_{i-1} \tag{1} $$

I have written a code to find the spectral density of this chain by making use of the node counting theorem - the $n^{th}$ eigenfrequency has $n-1$ nodes in the wavefunction. So, if I find the number of times the $x_i$'s cross zero at a given frequency, that is equal to the number of modes below that given frequency. I start with $x(0) = 0$ and fix $x(1)=1$ to calculate the rest of the sequence in terms of this. The sequence tends to blow up quickly so instead, I define $R_{i}$ as follows and re-write the equation:

$$ R_{i+1} = \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i}$$
$$ R_{i+1} = (2- m_i\omega^2) - \frac{1}{R_i} \tag{2} $$

Now I start with $R_1$ as a very large number (say $10^{20}$) and calculate the terms of the sequence. Here, the number of negative terms in the sequence at a given $\omega^2$ gives me the number of modes below that frequency.

How do I show the following using Eq (2): If I start with any other initial condition for $R_1$, for a given $\omega^2$, the number of sign changes in $x_i$ (or negative terms in $R_i$) can at most increase or decrease by 1.